# phaser 3 matter physics container for sprites with the custom shape

Tags: phaser-framework, texture-atlas, matter.js

I have a bunch of sprites with physics body json (created by physicsEditor), and I want to add text on it, I thought the best way is to use the **container with matter** physics:

```
 preload(){
    this.load.atlas('ballSheet', '/media/ballsGreen.png', '/media/ballsGreen.json');
    this.load.json('ballShapes', '/media/ballsGreenPhy.json');
}
```

and in create function creating sprites:

```
var ballShapes = this.cache.json.get('ballShapes');
for (i ; i< init_words.length;i++){
     var tempBall = this.add.sprite((canvasWidth)/2, -100*i, 'ballSheet', 'ballGreen100.png', {shape: ballShapes.ballGreen100 });
     var temp = this.add.text(canvasWidth/2, -100*i, init_words[i], { font: '34px Arial', fill: '#00ffff' });
     var container = this.add.container(0,0,[tempBall,temp]);
     this.matter.add.gameObject(container).setFrictionAir(0.001).setBounce(0.20);
}
```

there is a similar example from labs.phaser:
[phaser 3 example](https://labs.phaser.io/view.html?src=src%5Cgame%20objects%5Ccontainer%5Cmatter%20physics%20sprite%20test.js)
but it's not working properly,mostly when adding container as gameObject to matter:

```
this.matter.add.gameObject(container)
```